# Using MySQL, I have a location, how do i find out who is willing to travel to my location based on the radius they are willing to travel

Tags: mysql, math, geospatial

A very very tricky one.

I have a list of people and their locations with how far they are willing to travel from each.

```
id |  lat    | lon    | travel_radius
1  |  1.0131 | 3.2932 |     3 
2  |  1.1421 | 3.4115 |     10
```

now i provide a lat and lon, how do i find out which of the above radiuses will intersect with the provided lat and lon?

Comment: What are the units of `travel_radius`? MySQL doesn't have lat/long math that I'm aware of. It would be better to store your lat long as a WKT or geometry to take advantage of st_contains, buffer, etc. to find overlaps.

Comment: radius is in kilometers... im quite new to this so would appreciate if someone could have some pointers how this might be done... either in sql or a javascript algorithm or something something